# What is the meaning behind the linear differential equation standard form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In differential equations this form is often used to describe a differential equation:

[image]

I'm confused what this equation is saying. If you add all the derivatives of a function of $x$ together you get another function of $x$? What is $G(x)$ and how and why is it related to $y(x)$? Why are we adding the derivatives of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equation you've listed, $G(x)$ has nothing to do with $y(x)$. $G(x)$ is just any polynomial: $0$, $\sin{x}$, $x^2$, whatever is defined in your problem.

The reason we write differential equations in this form is because when solving them, we first find the *homogeneous* solution and then we find the *particular* solution.

The homogeneous solution is the solution to the equation when $G(x)$ is identically zero. There are many ways to find the homogenous solution, but I won't bore you with details an ODE textbook can give you.

The particular solution is any *one* solution that solves the whole equation, where we don't ignore $G(x)$. To get the solution to the whole ODE, we add the homogeneous and particular solutions together.

If you're wondering why we write the LHS how we do, think of an analogy to polynomials. Each of the functions $a_0(x), a_1(x), \ldots$ are like coefficients, and each of the derivatives $y', y'', \ldots$ are like powers of your independent variable.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my real question was why it is useful to write this way, which you helped with.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the general linear differential equation of degree $n$. $G(x)$ is just some function of $x$ not involving $y$. Such a DE can have terms involving the $n$th or lower derivatives of $y$.

For instance the (homogeneous, meaning $G(x)=0$) DE

$$2y''(x)-y(x)=0$$

has $n=2$ and $a_2=-1$, $a_1=0$ and $a_0=2$. These constants could also be a function of $x$, and that's why the notation $a_k(x)$ is used.

Does this answer your question? If not, let me know in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Differential equations often appear in physics.

For instance, when a body moves, it has a position, a speed (derivative of the position) and an acceleration (derivative of the speed). By Newton's law, the acceleration is proportional to the sum of the forces. If the body is attached to a spring, there will be a force that depends on the position. If there is some friction, the force will depend on the speed. And if an external force is applied, there will be a term which doesn't depend on these. The motion equation will be like

$$mx''(t)+fx'(t)+sx(t)=e(t).$$

A key property is linearity. It says that the effect of a sum of causes is the sum of the effects of the individual causes. This is why the equation has the form of a linear combination of the derivatives. Most physical systems behave linearly, at least as a first approximation.